# Class can't find attribute I am specifying(PySide, Maya)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

I am learning  Python/PySide for Maya from time to time and today I tried to make a class with PySide.

I am trying to make a window with an empty list inside. I have done the same code structure with usual Maya commands for UI and it worked.

But when I tried to do same with PySide, I got `AttributeError: 'VL_Test' object has no attribute 'ui_fk'` error.

What am I missing?

> Code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui

try:
    from PySide import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
    from shiboken import wrapInstance    
except:
    from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
    from shiboken2 import wrapInstance  


def getMayaWindow():
    pointer = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if pointer is not None:
        return wrapInstance(long(pointer), QtWidgets.QWidget)


class VL_Test(object):
    def showUI(cls):
        win = cls()
        win.create()
        return win

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = 'vl_test'
        self.title = 'Test Remastered'
        self.size = (1000,650)
        self.supportsToolAction = False
        self.actionName = 'Create and Close'
        self.applyName = 'Create'
        self.closeName = 'Close'

    def create(self):
        if cmds.window(self.window, exists= True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window ,window= True)
        self.parentWindow = getMayaWindow()
        self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(self.parentWindow)
        self.mainWindow.setObjectName(self.window)
        self.mainWindow.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Windows')
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
        self.ui_fk()

        self.mainWindow.show()

    def ui_fk(self):
        self.fkStrandGroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('FK Joints:')
        self.fkStrandLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(fkStrandGroupBox)
        self.fkStrandGroupBox.setLayout(fkStrandLayout)

        self.fkListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.fkStrandLayout.addWidget(fkListWidget)

testWindow = VL_Test()
testWindow.create()
```

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct. Sometimes this happens when I've indented too far or not far enough when def'ing.

Comment: I checked few times. It doesn't look like indentation problem.

Comment: I confirm it sounds like something missing indent. I don't yave maya so I can't try :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just lose some `self` before these variables `fkStrandGroupBox` `fkStrandLayout` `fkListWidget`

I run it in Maya 2017, it seems ok.

[image]

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui

try:
    from PySide import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
    from shiboken import wrapInstance
except:
    from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
    from shiboken2 import wrapInstance


def getMayaWindow():
    pointer = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if pointer is not None:
        return wrapInstance(long(pointer), QtWidgets.QWidget)


class VL_Test(object):
    def showUI(cls):
        win = cls()
        win.create()
        return win

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = 'vl_test'
        self.title = 'Test Remastered'
        self.size = (1000,650)
        self.supportsToolAction = False
        self.actionName = 'Create and Close'
        self.applyName = 'Create'
        self.closeName = 'Close'

    def create(self):
        if cmds.window(self.window, exists= True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window ,window= True)
        self.parentWindow = getMayaWindow()
        self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(self.parentWindow)
        self.mainWindow.setObjectName(self.window)
        self.mainWindow.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Windows')
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
        self.ui_fk()

        self.mainWindow.show()

    def ui_fk(self):
        self.fkStrandGroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('FK Joints:')
        self.fkStrandLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.fkStrandGroupBox)
        self.fkStrandGroupBox.setLayout(self.fkStrandLayout)

        self.fkListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.fkStrandLayout.addWidget(self.fkListWidget)

        # test
        self.fkListWidget.addItems(['a', 'b', 'c'])

testWindow = VL_Test()
testWindow.create()
```

---

And, if you use `PySide`, don't add `QtWidgets`, because PySide have no `QtWidgets`

I prefer to use `import *`, because I am lazy.

```
try:
    from PySide.QtGui import *
    from PySide.QtCore import *
    from shiboken import wrapInstance
except:
    from PySide2.QtCore import *
    from PySide2.QtGui import *
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
    from PySide2.QtUiTools import *
    from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
```

If you consider the compatibility, you can try this.
https://github.com/mottosso/Qt.py